# Control-M - Raise a shout if any of the jobs inside a folder fails

Tags: control-m

I need to notify an email distribution list if one or more jobs inside a **folder** is failed. I don't need any details about which job failed, but only a one-liner notification.

We have configured email shouts in our Control-M jobs configuration at a folder level. It's configured as follows:

- Under 'Actions' tab, inside 'Notifications after job completion' section
- The condition reads like this: `When Folder Ended Not OK Send Notification to <our email shout destination>`

However, it's not raising any shouts in case any one of the job fails, because even if the folder is marked in red colour, the folder status isn't set to 'Not OK' due to other pending jobs. One way to achieve this is to configure shout for all jobs inside that folder.

Is there any way we can set a shout at folder level if any one of the jobs in the folder fails?

Comment: Are you saying group level but not folder level?

Comment: I need to set a shout at Folder Level (if any one of the jobs inside that folder fails)

Comment: `if any one of the jobs inside that folder fails` are you saying all these jobs are control-m job?

Comment: Yes, all are Control-M jobs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a smart folder you can create an 'on-do action' to achieve this.

The logic would be: On 'Folder's number of Failures = 1' Do 'Notify' Destination 'Mail'

[image: Send Email on Folder Failure = 1]